# Is there a false loop in writing algorithms in IEEEtran?

Tags: algorithms, ieeetran, algorithmicx

The [IEEEtran manual](https://ctan.mirror.globo.tech/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf), suggests using `algorithmicx.sty` to write an algorithm and prohibits `algorithm.sty`:

> However, do *not* use the floating algorithm environment of `algorithm.sty` or `algorithm2e.sty` as the only floating structures IEEE uses are figures and tables.

On the other hand, to use the layouts of `algorithmicx.sty`, *e.g.,* `algpseudocode`, we have to use `algorithm.sty`, as according to the [`algorithmicx.sty` manual](https://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.pdf):

> To create floating algorithms you will need `algorithm.sty`

and without `\usepackage{algorithm}` it shows an error that

> LaTeX Error: Environment algorithm undefined.

Then, how can we break this false loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't *need* [`algorithm`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithms). `algorithm` just provides a float to put stuff in, and that stuff can be virtually anything. The [IEEE manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf) (section **B. Algorithms**) mentions:

> IEEE publications use the `figure` environment to contain
> algorithms ...

So you'll need

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

% <some preamble stuff>

\usepackage{algpseudocode}

% <more preamble stuff>

\begin{document}

% <part of your document>

\begin{figure}
  \caption{<your algorithm caption>}
  \begin{algorithmic}[.]
    \State ...
    % <more pseudocode>
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{figure}

% <more of your document>

\end{document}
```